# Are there any way to farm legendary shields beyond the Grinder?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've understood that you can try to farm legendaries weapons at the Grinder using correct recipes. However I haven't found any ways to farm legendary shields. I'm trying to get **The Sham**. So far the only other ways I'm aware of getting a legendary shield are:

- Spamming Nina's machines hoping for luck.
- Getting lucky on story bosses (unfortunately, unless I'm mistaken you can't farm those once they're dead).

Are there any reliable ways to farm legendary shields in *Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel*?

Comment: I think you can farm Deadlift, as an example, but probably not every boss.

Answer (score 2):

In the last DLC `Claptastic Voyage`, there is a "simple" way to farm legendary shields.

You simply beat the DLC Boss over and over again. You'll get a random legendary shield with a 50% chance (at least in my experience). Ofc, he is extremely strong, so I'd recommend a few friends with enough firepower. In the past week, I've beaten him about 11 times and found a reogenator, a prismatic bulwark, a sham, a shooting star, a WTF and a kala (Only tested in UVHM).

The Sham itself can be farmed more easy by killing the RK-5 Jet, who has an increased droprate.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. When did this DLC came out ? I've never heard of it

Comment: The DLC was released at the 24th of March 2015. It is currently available in steam for 3.78€ (or something). I'd recommend you get it asap. Other noteable changes introduced with the DLC are an increased level cap (up to lvl 70), new weapons/shields, a new weapon rarity (glitch) and an entire and hilarious story. It's worth the money. But as i wrote, be warned. The boss is extremely strong.

Comment: I've just finished the stor of the DLC and what I assume is the final boss didn't drop a shield. Did I miss interpret something ?

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWER EXPLOITS A GLITCH IN THE GAME

bit of a late answer but its been bugging me that there isn't one, so if you don't mind using the duplication glitch/grinder all you've got to do is find one shield of the correct level from a vendor (took me about a half hour of flitting between elseer and Concordia)

host: start game in Concordia.

p2: sign in.

host: drop shield/any item you would like doubled.

p2:pick items up and walk past "new u station" to save, drop everything you would like and immediately sign out via home button (this does not give the game a chance to save so when you sign back in the weapons/items/shields that you had originally saved are still there plus what ever you had dropped).

host: pick up items - save.

p2: sign back in - repeat.

once all the shields you want have been accumulated grind three legendary shields together at the cost of no moonstones :D (sometimes you can get an exact copy of the three shields you have just ground, some times just the same type this happened to me first few grinds I had done, so dupe plenty of shields and persevere I've gotten an 81% sham from three identical whiskey tango foxtrot shields).

note!!! occasionally the game will kick you out because of a "sign in change" I believe gearbox has done this to circumvent this glitch from bl2 but it is still very possible provided you use the same save stations (I use the one behind the jump pad near the grinder) and only save when your host is the only one signed in, unless of course you loading your mule full of shields, then you need to save their inventory just the once so you don't lose all your shields.

I know its a very convoluted way of doing things but its the only way I could figure it out as they've nerfed all the drops, you cant farm any bosses apart from Irwajira, 
Nel and the Sentinel and also you can apply the same logic to grinding with moonstones( eg purple orange orange) as long as you use p2: to grind and drop the legendary, sign out, repeat you'll be fine

I hope this helps

Comment: Why not start such wall of text with a short description: "It is possible to duplicate legendary items and grind them endlessly"? Aside from that, the question was "how to farm shields", not "how to farm shields from other shields". What if the OP doesn't have a single legendary one?

Comment: fair point, I would point out that there is a much better chance of a orange shield drop from a vendor, as this would be the quickest way of obtaining a shield in the first place from then it would just be a case of following the steps, given the question asked, I believe this to be the only reliable way to consistently farm shields-not bosses (as there is about 4 bosses you can farm none of which drop legendary shields).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Lunar Launching station and farm Lost Legion Powersuit Noob or red coat and get 3 shooting stars then go to the grinder and grind them you can get almost any shield there.

Answer (score -1):

If you can find even ONE purple shield, dupe it until you have three. After that, you can repeatedly grind them until you get a legendary shield. Dupe THAT, and then use the grinder to get the shield you want. Definitely time-consuming, but worth the effort if you have the patience.